# Exclude products from Woocommerce variable product dropdown with variations prices

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, product-variations

In WooCommerce, based on *"[Woocommerce get variation product price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272733/woocommerce-get-variation-product-price/12290037#12290037)"* answer code, I have been using  the following to show the price beside each variation on my variable products dropdowns:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'display_price_in_variation_option_name' );
function display_price_in_variation_option_name( $term ) {
    global $wpdb, $product;

    $result = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT slug FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms WHERE name = '$term'" );

    $term_slug = ( !empty( $result ) ) ? $result[0] : $term;

    $query = "SELECT postmeta.post_id AS product_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS postmeta
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS products ON ( products.ID = postmeta.post_id )
        WHERE postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'attribute_%'
        AND postmeta.meta_value = '$term_slug'
        AND products.post_parent = $product->id";

    $variation_id = $wpdb->get_col( $query );

    $parent = wp_get_post_parent_id( $variation_id[0] );

    if ( $parent > 0 ) {
        $_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id[0] );
        return $term . ' (' . woocommerce_price( $_product->get_price() ) . ')';
    }
    return $term;
}
```

It works great on all products except one (which I use a separate plugin for as it's for a gift card).

Is it possible to exclude one specific product ID or a product category, OR for it to apply to only specific product categories? If so, what should be added to the code and where to apply that?

I also use Woo Discount Rules plugin for price discounts and that's the code included for that:

```
function woocs_fixed_raw_woocommerce_price_method($tmp_val, $product_data, $price){
    remove_filter('woocs_fixed_raw_woocommerce_price', 'woocs_fixed_raw_woocommerce_price_method', 10, 3);
    global $flycart_woo_discount_rules;
    if(!empty($flycart_woo_discount_rules)){
        global $product;
        if(empty($product)){
            $discount_price = $flycart_woo_discount_rules->pricingRules->getDiscountPriceOfProduct($product_data);
            if($discount_price !== null) $tmp_val = $discount_price;
        }
    }
    add_filter('woocs_fixed_raw_woocommerce_price', 'woocs_fixed_raw_woocommerce_price_method', 10, 3);

    return $tmp_val;
}
add_filter('woocs_fixed_raw_woocommerce_price', 'woocs_fixed_raw_woocommerce_price_method', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** *(for Woo Discount Rules plugin usage - see at the end)*

Your code is a bit outdated since WooCommerce 3: `woocommerce_price()` is replaced by `wc_Price()`

In the following revisited code, you will be able to exclude some product Ids:

```
// for woocommerce 3+
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'display_price_in_variation_option_name' );
function display_price_in_variation_option_name( $term_name ) {
    global $product, $wpdb;

    if( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') )
        return $term_name;

    // Excluding product IDs
    $excluded_product_ids = array(37, 53);
    if( in_array( $product->get_id(), $excluded_product_ids ) )
        return $term_name;

    if( $product->is_type('variable') && ! empty($term_name) ) {
        $term_slug = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT slug FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms WHERE name = '$term_name'");

        $term_slug = empty($term_slug) ? sanitize_title( $term_name ) : $term_slug;

        $variation_id = (int) $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT postmeta.post_id AS product_id
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS postmeta
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS products
                ON ( products.ID = postmeta.post_id )
            WHERE postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'attribute_%'
                AND postmeta.meta_value = '%s'
                AND products.post_parent = %d
        ", $term_slug, $product->get_id() ) );

        if( $variation_id > 0 ){
            $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );

            $term_name .= ' (' . strip_tags( wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $variation ) ) ) . ')';
        }
    }
    return $term_name;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme *(or active theme)*. Tested and works.

---

Maybe, to make it work with the [Woo Discount Rules](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-discount-rules/) plugin, try to replace:

```
$term_name .= ' (' . strip_tags( wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $variation ) ) ) . ')';
```

by:

```
$term_name .= ' (' . strip_tags( wc_price( $variation->get_price() ) ) . ')';
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I appreciate it. That worked in all cases except products that are discounted using the WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing plugin. That was the second part of the code above, which worked with the original code to show the discounted price in the variation dropdowns. Do I need to change that code as well for it to work?  Or is there a way to change the original code I provided to exclude a product as that was working for me with the discounted products as well (even though I understand it's outdated, but it was working). Thank you!

Comment: I tried that change but still didn't work, not sure why. I appreciate your updated code and will keep a copy, but since my original code was working other than excluding one product is it possible to add code to it to exclude a product?  I tried adding the code you provided for exclusion:
`// Excluding product IDs
    $excluded_product_ids = array(37, 53);
    if( in_array( $product->get_id(), $excluded_product_ids ) )
        return $term_name;`

under 
`global $wpdb, $product;`

It worked on product pages but when I add discounted products to the cart the cart page doesn't work.