# WooCommerce: Get price of chosen product variation

Tags: php, woocommerce, product-variations

I am making a custom add-on for my products on my WooCommerce webshop. Everything works as it should, but I only need one thing. When customers check the checkbox on the product page, $30 must be added to the original price of the selected variation.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_cart_item_data', 10, 3 );
function add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
        
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        $price = $product->get_price();
        
        if ($product->is_type( 'variable' )) {
            
            $var_price = $product->get_price_html();
            
            // extra pack checkbox
            if( ! empty( $_POST['addon-card'] ) ) {
                $cart_item_data['new_price'] = $var_price + 30;
            }
            
        } else {
            
            // extra pack checkbox
            if( ! empty( $_POST['addon-card'] ) ) {
                $cart_item_data['new_price'] = $price + 30;
            }
            
        }

return $cart_item_data; 
}
```

This part: `if( ! empty( $_POST['addon-card'] ) )` check if the checkbox is checked.

My problem is here:

```
$var_price = $product->get_price_html();

// extra pack checkbox
if( ! empty( $_POST['addon-card'] ) ) {
   $cart_item_data['new_price'] = $var_price + 30;
}
```

The value of `$var_price`  is just 0.

**So I try to figure out how I can get the price of the chosen variation.**

I have tried with `get_variation_prices()` and `get_variation_price()`  but without any luck...

**UPDATE**
I have tried to implement the code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272733/woocommerce-get-variation-product-price). With that code I can get the price of the chosen variation, but I can no longer add the $30.

Comment: May that help you [get_variation_price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272733/woocommerce-get-variation-product-price)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tried to implement the code you referred to. The positive thing is that I can now find the price of the chosen variation. The problem now is that I can not plus it with the $30.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below WooCommerce hook to change price dynamically?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'custom_variation_price_change', 10, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price', 'custom_variation_price_change', 10, 3 );   

function custom_variation_price_change( $price, $variation, $product ) {
   
      // add some conditional code as per your requirement  
    
       $price = $price+30;
        
}
```

Comment: Hey. Thank you for your comment. I've tried with the code you added, but my page will crash if I use it ...
I have tried to make it very simple, by just pasting the code as you made it, without adding any conditionals.